# Trouble making vtkOBJWriter

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, vtk

I am trying to make vtkOBJWriter (second part in trying to convert from a vtk file to an obj file, as advised from http://www.vtk.org/pipermail/vtkusers/2012-April/122774.html). The files are at https://github.com/daviddoria/vtkOBJWriter . When I try to cmake .. and then make, I get an error that vtkOBJWriterExample.cxx:59:11: error: ‘class vtkOBJWriter’ has no member named ‘SetInputData’ . This makes sense because I don't see any such member in the vtkOBJWriter file. I was wondering if anyone was able to correct this without deleting vtkOBJWriterExample completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the documentation and the exemple, as you can say, neither vtkOBJWriter nor vtkPolyDataAlgorithm (mother class) has SetInputData methods, but vtkPolyDataAlgorithm  has a SetInput method.

What is your VTK version ? [SetInput methods has been replaced](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Replacement_of_SetInput) by SetInputData() in VTK6.

2 solutions :

- change your VTK version: download the latest VTK6, replace your old version with it and try to rebuild.
- Modify the example using the methods of the version 5

Comment: That worked, thanks :) I thought I had VTK 6, but looking at the error statements outputted in the terminal, it said VTK 5.8.8, so I changed it to SetInput and it works